# How to inject a .NET provider (OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a solution on how to inject IApplicationUserManager into a OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.cs.

This is the sample I'm looking at now: (https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Providers/SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs).

The difference is that I'm using [dependency injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (Autofac). Their AuthRepository would be my ApplicationUserManager.

Injected by:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(ApplicationUserManager)).As(typeof(IApplicationUserManager)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Do you have any ideas or even better solutions?